# Como sincronizar escrita de arquivo

Tags: asp

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um aplicação ASP clássico e preciso gravar um JSON num arquivo data.json. Problema é que vários usuários poderão requisitar a gravação neste arquivo, gostaria de saber qual melhor solução para este problema? Queria que evitasse o erro que dois usuários requisitem a gravação no arquivo ao mesmo tempo. Sei que é difícil de ocorrer mas não é impossível. Então haveria alguma maneira de sincronizar a escrita evitando que vários usuários requisitem a escrita ao mesmo tempo fazendo um de cada vez colocando-os em uma fila?

Eis o código:

```
dim filesys, filetxt

Dim path,pastalocal
pastalocal = split(Request.ServerVariables("script_name"),"/")
path = Server.MapPath("/"&pastalocal(1))

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8


Dim lineData
Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set fs = fso.OpenTextFile(path&"\data2.json", ForReading, true) 
Do Until fs.AtEndOfStream 
    lineData = fs.ReadLine      
Loop 

fs.close: set fs = nothing

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(path&"\data2.json", ForWriting, True)
If lineData = "" Then
    filetxt.Write(Request.Form("dataJson"))
Else
    filetxt.Write(lineData&","&Request.Form("dataJson"))
End If
filetxt.Close
```

Comment: Apresente o código de como você está abrindo o arquivo para escrita

Comment: Já inclui o código @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

A partir do momento que fazes este código:

```
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(path&"\data2.json", ForWriting, True)
```

qualquer outra tentativa de fazer outra abertura para escrita no ficheiro vai dar erro, para poderes abrir novamente para escrita tens de fazer

```
filetxt.Close
```

se colocares algo deste género :

```
on error goto erroAbertura
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(path&"\data2.json", ForWriting, True)
```

Assim parece-me que resolve o teu problema